# Is the smallest Pythagorean triple angle $\sim 4.9^\circ$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, pythagorean-triples

Pythagorean theorem $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$

Where $(a,b,c)$ are [Pythagorean triples](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PythagoreanTriple.html).

We are claiming that this inequality hold for all Pythagorean triples,
$${3-2\sqrt{2}\over 2}\le{ab\over c^2}$$

---

Let examine this inequality

$$3-2\sqrt{2}\le2\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}$$

$$4.9396...^\circ\le \theta$$

So what this is saying is that the smallest angle of a Pythagoras triples can't go below $4.9396^\circ$

**How can we show that this is true or false?**

Comment: Where did you get  (3−2√2)/2 from?

Comment: The OP may have not examined large enough hypoteneuses.  If you catalog triples up to hypoteneuse=100, it looks like the sine of the acute angle is at least 13/85.  We know from both currently posted answers that such a claim does not stand up to more rigorous testing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $a= 999999999999$, $b=2000000$ and $c=1000000000001$.  This is a Pythagorean triangle.  But $\arcsin(b/c) = 2\times 10^{-6}.$

Comment: Is this values of a,b and c are Pythagorean triple?

Comment: @GameOver Yes, just checked it on a multidigit calculator.

Comment: @GameOver Take $m=1\,000\,000$ and $n=1$. Then $a=m^2-n^2$, $b=2mn$, and $c=m^2+n^2$. Therefore, $a^2+b^2=c^2$.

Comment: Great counter-example, but can we prove that the inequalit in the OP is false?

Comment: @Dylan:  this counterexample proves the inequality in the OP is false.  Plug $a,b,c$ in and check it.

Comment: Fair enough. I wonder how OP came up with it.

Answer (score 1):

Not a chance for a nonzero minimum angle.  Suppose we render

$(2n+1)^2=(2n^2+2n+1)+(2n^2+2n)$.

Since the terms on the right differ by one unit the difference of squares factorization gives

$(2n+1)^2=(2n^2+2n+1)^2-(2n^2+2n)^2$.

And then

$(2n^2+2n+1)^2=(2n+1)^2+(2n^2+2n)^2$.

As $n$ is allowed to increase without bound the ratio of the smaller leg to the hypotenuse tends to a limit of zero and the angle opposite that leg does the same.  Also, of course, the larger acute angle has no limit below $90°$.